# How to make rsync synchronize contents of a directory but don't touch the permissions of directory itself?

Tags: rsync

I want to use rsync to synchronize a specific set of files from some directory on remote machine to local one. I run something like:

```
rsync -i -a --delete -f 'merge ~/files_list' x.x.x.x:/source/dir/ /target/dir/
```

The file `~/files_list` contains the specific list of filename patterns (with wildcards) to be synchronized, because there are more files in the remote directory and I want to copy only a specific subset. The `--delete` parameter is also important, as I want to delete from local machine the files that are no longer present on remote.

This works as expected, except one thing: it changes the owner and permissions of the `/target/dir` to the ones of `/source/dir`, which is unacceptable in my case.

How to get rid of this behavior? I can't believe there is no parameter to rsync that simply says something like "don't modify the top-level directory attributes", as it seems to be something that would be needed quite often...

The obvious solution of putting a `*` after `/source/dir/` does not work in my case, as it effectively disables `--delete`, and files that exist on target, but not on source are not deleted.

Is there any solution to this?

**Edit**: As I get a lot of answers telling me to not use `-a` or explicitly stating `--no-perms`: I **really do know** what `-a` means and it's there **on purpose**. I **do want** to have **everything synchronized** (including permissions and ownership) on the **contents of the directory**. I only want to **skip the directory itself**.

I wish there would be a switch to `rsync` that tells "don't do anything on the **topmost** directory". It really should.

Answer (score -1):

Add --no-perms --no-owner --no-group

Comment: You don't understand. I **do** want to have permissions, owner and group synchronized on **everything inside** the directory (I wouldn't use -a if I didn't want to). I only want to skip the **directory itself**.